# Table with function evaluated at a list

Tags: plotting, evaluation, list-manipulation

Supposed I have a function

```
f[a_] = a^2;
alist = {1, 10, 100, 1000};
```

I want to make a table of the values of `alist` and `f[a]` evaluated at `alist`. How should the syntax of the table be?

Comment: `Table[{a, f[a]}, {a, alist}]`.

Comment: Thread@{alist, f[alist]}

Comment: {#, f[#]} & /@ alist

Comment: `Transpose[{alist,f@alist}]`